# How to overwrite the namespace a class is defined in?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a package called `mypackage`. `mypackage` contains two files:
`__init__.py` and `module.py`.

`__init__.py` simply imports everything from `module.py`:

```py
from .module import *
```

In `module.py` I define the class `MyClass`:

```py
class MyClass:
    pass
```

When I use this package I can simply import `MyClass` via

```py
from mypackage import MyClass
```

shadowing the module `module.py`.
However, when I print the class, the output is

```
<class 'mypackage.module.MyClass'>
```

instead of the desired

```
<class 'mypackage.MyClass'>
```

Is there a way to tell `MyClass`, that it was defined in `__init__.py` instead of `module.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in `module.py`.

```
__name__ = 'mypackage'
class MyClass:
    pass
```

The `__name__` before you rewrite it is `mypackage.module`.